# 夏の投票キャンペーン (2015年)

Tags: 討議, 投票, キャンペーン

現在投票されていない投稿（質問・回答）は約3分の1になっています：

[image: 投稿毎のスコア配分]

投票は当サイトにとっては非常に大事な役割をしています。日本のプログラマーが検索で当サイトの質問・回答を見つけた時に、投票があると簡単に回答の質がわかるため、問題の解決にもつながります。

回答が存在しているだけではその回答がいいかどうかを判断できないため、**質問に回答があっても、その回答にプラス票がない場合は質問が未回答**として扱われます。結果的にスタック・オーバーフローでは未回答質問が多いです：

[image: 未回答質問の配分]

回答が存在している質問のうち約4分の3は、回答への投票が行われていません。もしこれらの回答に投票したら回答率が約75％から95％近くに上ります。

下記のリンクには回答のある「未回答」質問のリストがあります。投票しませんか？

[投票頑張りましょう！](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/search?q=answers%3A1..100+isanswered%3A0)

もちろん上記の基準とは関係なく、投票が多いほど日本のプログラマーへの支援になります。

Comment: 1人でも投票したら上記検索には引っかからなくなってしまうと思うのですが、回答への投票数の少ない質問を検索することはできるでしょうか？

Comment: @unarist 上記の検索は回答のある質問の中、回答にプラス票はない投稿です。だから上記の検索で対応していると思います。投票すると（数分後）検索結果から削除されますので、利用できると思います。

Comment: ああすみません、「未回答の質問を探す」という意味では正しいクエリです。ただ、ここでヒットする質問はあまり目を向けられなかった質問が多いと思うので、誰か一人投票した時点で再び埋もれるのは勿体無いなと思ったのです。そこで「スコアが3以下の回答しかない質問」とかを探せないものかと…。

Comment: @unarist この検索でスコア１の回答を探せますが、このかんじかな？http://ja.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=active&q=is%3aanswer%20score%3a1..1

Comment: できれば質問の方を検索結果に出したかったのですが、まあそうなりますよね…

Comment: @unarist そうなら、[Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/)しかないですが、毎週月曜日にしか更新しないので、あまりやくに立たないと思います。上記の検索に多くな制限があるので、回答に投票あまりない質問等は検索出来ません。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ありがとうございます！

#### 投票が**約２倍**になりました：

[image: 投票データ]

#### 回答率が2.4％上がりました

前：74.4%
後：76.8%

#### 0スコアの投稿が約100減りました

前：3,167投稿
後：3,072投稿

この投票率を更に上がりましょう！