# 投票することの大切さについて

Tags: 討議, 投票の仕方

スタック・オーバーフローのコミュニティが日本のデベロッパーのみなさんにとってさらにより良い環境となるためにできることについて、少し私の思うところをシェアしたいと思います。2017年の1月からの新規ユーザー登録者数を、振り返ってみましょう。2017年の6月の時点では600人もの新規登録がありましたが、それから減少が続き今年の1月には約370人となりました。これは新しくスタック・オーバーフローを訪問した人々のサイトへの参加の意欲、クオリティの高い内容をみなに提供したいかどうか、が減少している傾向にあるように見受けられます。新しい訪問者が初心者であれエキスパートであれ、コンテンツのクオリティこそが知識を共有したい理由なのではないでしょうか。その点を考慮し、クオリティを向上させるための簡単な方法をご紹介したいと思います。それはコミュニティをよりよくする為に私たち誰もが今すぐにできることです。

スタック・オーバーフローを、クオリティの高い質問・回答が期待できる、自分が使い続けたくなるようなQ&Aサイトに育てることに少しでも興味がある人は、まずは「投票」をお願いします！

「投票」はコンテンツのクオリティを向上させるために無くてはならないものです。あなたが質問や解答にプラス投票を投じるにせよマイナス投票を投じるにせよ、投票頂くこと自体がサイトを向上させるのに非常に重要です。これらのボタンを使用することによって、あなたが内容を確認し、コンテンツの有益性、明確さ、正確さについて、あなたの考えを他の皆さんに共有したことを意味します。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

スタック・オーバーフローでは得票数の多いコンテンツほど上に表示され、参考になるものがわかりやすくなっています。投票することによって、有益な情報を検索しやすくなります。私たちはフォーラムではなく、何が有益でそうでないのかをコミュニティから意見を得ながらキュレートするQ&Aサイトなのです。それらなしではノイズだらけのサイトになってしまいます。情報を共有しても、それが常に有益でうまくまとめられたものであるとは限りません。投票は投稿者を攻撃するというわけではなく、どの質問やどの回答が正しく重要なのか、有益なのかそうでないのかを知らせるあなたの意思表示なのです。私たちはおそらくこれまでにそれほど有益ではない情報を共有したことが（人生の中で）あると思いますが、それだからと言って私たちが役立たずだというわけではありません。それはただ、私たちの投稿を、聞き手が何を必要としているかにあわせて少し編集する必要があるだけなのです。

トップページを見ると、現時点では質問への投票も回答への投票も非常に少ない状態す。残念ながらこれでは訪問者に「ここではあまり交流がされていない」という印象を与えてしまうのではないでしょうか。サイトへの訪問数自体が少ないようにも見えてしまうのではないでしょうか。しかし実際には、全くそうではないのです！スタック・オーバーフローへの訪問数は2017年1月の時点では約365,000人、しかし今年の1月には約455,000人と、実はかつてないほどのトラフィックがあるのです！しかしユーザーの参加が活発でない為に、サイトのコンテンツやクオリティ向上にあまり関心がないようなそんな間違った印象を新しい訪問者に与えてしまっているのではないかと思うのです。そこで、投票が大切になってきます！

あなたの投票はスタック・オーバーフローの方向性を左右し、コミュニティの成功に繋がります。このコミュニティの大切なユーザーによって毎日作られているコンテンツを通じて交流しながらキュレートしていく事で他の仲間たちとあなたの考えを共有していることになるのです。このサイトは日本のデベロッパーの皆さんのサイトであり、他の日本のデベロッパーの皆さんとって何が重要で役に立つのか、何が良いクオリティであるのかを見極めることが必要となってきます。この素晴らしいサイトを成長させる為にも、ぜひ投票してください！

Answer (score 11):

### 提案: 投票キャンペーンを行いませんか？

2015年に2度、投票キャンペーンが行われ、実績も出ているようです。

- [新春の投票キャンペーン](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1797/19110)
- [夏の投票キャンペーン](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1897/19110)

たとえば[この質問リスト](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/search?q=answers%3A1..100%20isanswered%3A0)は、投票を始めるきっかけになるでしょう。

Comment: 他サイトの方から「投票キャンペーンを行うと無意味な投票をする人が増えて "良い" 投稿をソートするための機能が失われてしまうかもしれない」というご指摘を受け、一理あるな、と思ったのでコメントしておきます。

Answer (score 7):

### 提案: 投票ボタンをもっと目立たせませんか？

日本語版スタック・オーバーフローにおいて1回でも投票したことがあるユーザーの中で、投票回数の[統計を取ってみました](https://data.stackexchange.com/ja/query/825507/votes-distribution-of-regular-users-who-have-cast-votes#graph)。横軸が投票回数、縦軸がユーザー数です。

[image: 投票回数の統計グラフです。投票回数20回以下のユーザーが1000人規模と極端に多く、それ以外のユーザーは多くても二桁に留まっています。]

投票回数が20回未満のユーザーを除いて統計を取っても、以下のようになります。

[image: 投票回数20回未満のユーザーを除いた上での投票回数のグラフです。この場合も、20〜40のユーザーが98人と多く、それ以外のユーザーは多くても30程度です。]

どちらもロングテールのグラフになっていることが分かります。このグラフの形自体は本家 Stack Overflow でも[似たようなもの](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/825513/votes-distribution-of-regular-users-who-have-cast-votes#graph)で、日本語版でも本家でも

- 投票の仕方を知っていても、20回未満しか投票したことがないユーザーが多くを占めていて、
- 投票数トップのユーザーでも全投票数からみると僅かな量しか投票していない（[日本語版では3%](https://data.stackexchange.com/ja/query/825529/ratio-of-votes-per-a-user#resultSets)、本家では0.1%未満）

ということが分かります。

このことから、投票量を増やす1つの戦略として、ユーザーに投票を促すよう UI を変更し、より多くのユーザーが投票することが考えられます。投票したことがあるログイン済みユーザーが投票するだけでも、投票量は大きく増えそうです。

正直なところ、何かしらの働きかけを行って投票数を増やさなければいけないのであれば、それはデザイン・ミスなのではないかと思います。本家と日本語版で分布に差があるのであればユーザー層の問題にできましたが、そうでもなさそうです。そこで、よりユーザーに投票を促すデザインにするのはどうだろうと思いました。

いかがでしょうか？

#### 追記 (投票しているユーザーの数について)

上の方で「他と差が無い」と書きましたが、統計の取り方によってはそうでもなさそうです。

投票の数ではなく、投票したユーザー数を見てみました。[投票者のランキングページ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=quarter)によると、2018年1月〜3月24日までに (10票以上? [要調査]) 投票したユーザーは36名いるようです。また、同じ期間に一度でもログインした状態でこのサイトを訪れたユーザーは[3,823名でした](https://data.stackexchange.com/ja/query/829936/users-after-2018-1-quarter#resultSets)。

アクティブなユーザー数と比較して、この投票者数は正直少なくないですか？　実際、他のローカル版スタック・オーバーフローとユーザー数の比として比較すると少ないです。下の表が、他言語版についても同様の統計をとってみた結果の表です。

```
   | #(voted users) | #(active users) |   %
ja |             36 |            3823 | 0.94
es |            239 |           21086 | 1.13
pt |            325 |           23007 | 1.41
ru |            563 |           35752 | 1.57
```

もっとたくさんの人に投票して欲しいです。そのためにも、投票の存在をポップアップ表示などで目立たせて、多くの人にリーチしたいです（本当に効果があるのかは、分かりませんが――）。

他にアイディアのある方はいらっしゃいませんでしょうか？

Comment: この投票ランキングは、マイナス投票でも、投票をしたとカウントされるのでしょうか？どうやらそのように見えますね。

Comment: はい。そうだったと記憶しています。

Comment: 投票者のランキングに乗っているユーザーは、全員が11票以上入れているようですね。たぶん、10票以下のユーザーは乗らないのでしょう。（他ローカライズ版との比較に使う分には影響ないと思いますが）

Comment: 投票するユーザーの率が `ja < es < pt < ru` であるのは、コンテンツ量をそのまま反映したもので、私としては意外ではないです。 例えば質問数は `ja 14,560 < es 51,486 < pt 98,555 < ru 201,294` です。 コンテンツが多いほど、自分が評価可能かつ評価したい対象に当る確率が増えますから、その結果と考えられます。 もちろん、Juan Mさんの考えに従えば因果関係が逆で、日本語版は投票率が少ないから参加者が少なく、コンテンツ（投稿）も少ないのだ、ということになるかも知れませんが。

Comment: @mjy ご指摘ありがとうございます。10票の件は、誰が投票したのか分からないようにするためにありえる条件だと思います。真偽は分かりませんがひとまずこの点を追記しておきました。

Answer (score 4):

**投票意思の確認**

質問者は自分の疑問を解決するためにここを訪れる方がほとんどだと思います。
一方、回答者は自分の知識を質問者へ与え、信用度を獲得、情報の共有、バッジの獲得等が目的となっています。
　しかし、投票はコミュニティ貢献の性格が強いと感じます。彼等は、個人的な目的をもって参加されており、それで充分だと判断されているのではないでしょうか。

何らかの方法で意識調査をしてみたらどうかと思うのですが、投票をされない方が、参加されるとは少し考えにくいですね。

**投票基準の確認**

ヘルプなどを見ればいい質問の基準がある程度書いてありますが、
ボタンを押すときにも表れます。

趣旨が明確
　実用的
　建設的
　調査の跡がある
　試行錯誤の跡がある
　
　回答は、それを見た人が役に立ったか役に立たなかったかで、直感的に入れることが出来ます。
しかし、質問に対してはどうでしょうか。
　　
　上の基準等をより明確にわかりやすくし、それに当てはめるような質問をするように励行すれ　ば、ほとんど機械的に投票を入れるようにする。（強制はできないんですけどね。）そうすれ　　ば、もしかすると、投票も貰えるし、質問を良くしようという意欲が高まり、一石二鳥かも知れ　ません。有志の方たちから、積極的にこうした質問に投票を入れて行けば、気運も動くのではな　いですか？

よりコミュニティのために投票が行われているのだという気持ちにもなれ、投票者たちも、信用度と投票の一致を感じることができるのではないかなと考えます。
　
過去のMETAの論争を見ると、最初の質問に価値を置いている方が多いように感じました。
　
　投票というものを利用し、それを基準とリンクさせるという方法は無理でしょうか？
　
　私は「役に立つ質問」、変な表現ですが、そういう質問に投票が入れられているような気がして、投票基準がよくわからないという印象を受けた事があります。それとも私の勘違いでしょうか。

例えば、聞きたかったけど、投稿はしなかった質問。興味を惹かれる質問。面白い角度から考えた質問。なかなか見られないレアな質問、疑問に思っていたけど、コードが動いたからとりあえず胸にしまっておいた疑問、その質問の回答が、役に立ちそうな質問として現れた時などです。

投票をするほうが盛り上がるのは確かですが、恐らく慎重な方や厳格な方が多いのではないかと
推察します。そうした方たちの意向に沿うように、投票システムを敷いて行った方がいいかな
と考えました。

回答は、そのユーザーがどのライブラリや言語を取っているかによって、役に立たないほうが多いのではないかと考えます。例えば私はpython,pygame,(qt,pyqt),pysideを中心に動いて　 いますけれども,少なくとも今では、c#やphpとか言われても「私には」役に立たないものばかりだからです。アクティブなユーザーの中でも、興味ある分野によって、さらに投票機会は狭まるという悩みがあります。

そういう意味で、投票を増やすには、ユーザーさんたちの言語やライブラリなどの幅広い知識、他言語への興味が、広く浅くでも存在している必要はあるのかもしれません。これはさすがにコントロールできないかなと思いますが、どうでしょうか。

そうでないとするならば、
例えば、自分に今のところ関係なくても、
　**・時間の短縮につながりそう。

　・似た言語で考え方が参考になる。

　・プログラミングの知識を補う。　

　・散らばっている情報が集約されている。

　・より理解を深める。

　・別の角度からのいい捉え方！

　・基本を良くとらえた回答で、初学者にもわかりやすい。

　・具体例やたとえがうまく、わかりやすく工夫されて論じられている！**
　等の、ダイレクトに役に立つのももちろん、若干緩い基準で、役に立つと考えれば、投票をするのはいきすぎでしょうか？
　・コード（便利なメソッドや関数）の引き出しが増える
　・質問者の質問に率直に答えている。
　ほか色々
　役に立つというのは、自分にとってだけでしょうか？それとも、ほかの人にとっても役立ちそうという意味でもいいのでしょうか？

**人を増やす(減らさない)**
基本となるのはユーザーの数です。数が多いわりに投票が少ないのが問題になっているのはわかりますが、やはり基本だと思います。増やすのは難しいですが、減らすのは食い止めることが出来そうです。ユーザーは投票の源泉ですし、質問の源泉、回答の源泉です。
　
　先日、集中的にマイナス投票が投下され、サイトを去られた方がいらっしゃいました。質問を改善するつもり？が、質問者までも傷つけてしまう事があるようです。虫歯が出来たから、治療をしてくれたとしても、健康的な歯まで傷つける歯医者は信用できませんよね？
　特に初心者の方の様でしたので、人を尊重する事は投票云々以前に大切なことだと考えます。
　その方は、将来良い質問を何個も出してくださる方かも知れませんし、誰かの回答者になった方かもしれません。さらに言えば、投票者になられた方かも知れません。
　少なくとも私はこういう意識を持っていたいかなと考えています。

**編集の励行と受忍**
　上の投票基準に合いそうで合わないことも多いと思います。追加の情報を求めたり、編集を行ったりして、投票基準に一致したと判断すれば、ほぼ機械的に投票をするのがいいんじゃないでしょうか？編集の機運も高まるかもしれませんし、それで自分の質問が基準に会い、いい質問となり、信用度を貰えるのならうれしいかもしれません。

**時間は投票の基準ではない**
 好い質問といい回答も、時間が立てばとたんに投票をされなくなるような気がしています。一番投票されたときは、その質問や回答が出された最初のとき。更新されたすぐ後。
　しかし、本来基準に一致した質問であるか、回答であるかが投票をするかどうかを決めるものなのに、時間で目に触れられなくなったからということが、投票されなくなる理由というのはおかしい気がします。
　せいぜい一週間もしないうちに、投票は止まるようです。投票に積極的な人が少ないためかもしれませんので、時間だけが問題ではないかも知れませんが、気になったので挙げておきます。
ちなみに、私は信用度は、貢献度と言ってもいいのではないかなと考えます。

一生懸命考えてみました。色々突っ込みどころはあるかもしれませんが、お手柔らかに。

以上です。

Comment: 強く賛成します。このサイトに参加したての頃、私は「趣旨が明確」が投票理由になるとは思っていませんでした。最近は質問としてしっかりしているだけでも upvote のひとつの理由にしています。この違いだけでも自分としては大きかったです。

Comment: 関連のないコメントですが、私が現時点で2番目とは驚きました。もっと評価されてもいい質問や回答はあるように思うのですが、私自身の基準が少し緩いのでしょうか。皆さんの古い質問や回答もたまに眺めて勉強していこうと思います。投票もします。

Comment: マイナス投票って微妙と思います。ベテランの方は今更でしょうが、最初から、マイナス投票されたら、かなり凹むと思いますが、どうなのでしょうか? コメントも無しでのマイナスだと、なぜ、ダメなのかも分からないですね。　今、次のお薦めで、マイナス投票と表示されますが、すごく違和感。

Comment: @greentea 凹みます。私は最初に来た投票がマイナスでした。コメントなしですね。何が悪いのかわかりませんでした。入れる人はあまり気にしてないのでしょうが、入れられる方は結構こたえますね。編集すれば治るのだという事も知らなかったのでなおさらきつかったです。確か在日英国SOFの人がコメントで注意ヲしてくれたのが印象に残っています。入れられても冷静に編集が出来ればいいですが、結構それどころじゃなくなります。たまに本当に無関係な投稿をされる方がいらっしゃるので、マイナス投票はその人に入れましょう。また、本当に入れる時にはコメントを残してあげるといいですね。ヘルプにもそう書いてありますから、権利も使い方と使い時かもしれません。