# 日本語版のトップページは特別に投票が少ないですか？

Tags: 討議, 投票

先日、コミュニティーマネージャーのJuan Mさんより[投票を呼びかける投稿がありました](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2659/3054)。
これは日本語版にのみ投稿されたようですから、Stack Overflow全体の話ではなく、Stack Overflow日本語版に関して憂慮を述べられたものと思います。

> トップページを見ると、現時点では質問への投票も回答への投票も非常に少ない状態です
>   残念ながらこれでは訪問者に「ここではあまり交流がされていない」という印象を与えてしまうのではないでしょうか。

この、コミュニティーマネージャーによる「日本語版においては投票が少ないゆえに、参加者が少ない」という現状認識が正しいのか、私は疑問に思いました。

#### 日本語版のトップページは特別に投票が少ないですか？

まずは、そもそもの話になりますが、Stack Overflow日本語版においては特別に投票が少ない（との印象を与えている）というのが本当なのか、みなさんのご意見・印象を伺いたいです。

他言語のコミュニティーのトップページと比較して:

- https://stackoverflow.com/
- https://es.stackoverflow.com/
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/
- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/

直接の競合であるTeratailと比較して:

- https://teratail.com/

#### 日本語版はノイズを排除できていないですか？

また、

> それらなしではノイズだらけのサイトになってしまいます。

といった言及はトップページに限らずサイト全体のことと思います。
現状としてStack Overflow日本語版は、他言語版やTeratailと比較してノイズが多いでしょうか？

Comment: 「印象」の話なので実際の統計についておっしゃりたい訳ではないと思い、コメントにて投稿いたします。本家および他言語版スタック・オーバーフローに対して、スコアごとの投稿数の統計を取ってみました: [本家](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/829354/score-distribution#resultSets) ／ [ja](https://data.stackexchange.com/ja/query/829354/score-distribution#resultSets) ／ [es](https://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/829354/score-distribution#resultSets) ／ [pt](https://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/829354/score-distribution#resultSets) ／ [ru](https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/829354/score-distribution#resultSets)

Comment: @nekketsuuu 正確に言うと、サイトのビジターにどういった印象を与えているか知りたい、ということですので、必ずしも回答いただく方自身の印象でなくとも構いません。数的根拠を持って回答していただくのも歓迎です。統計に関してはよく解らないですが、`WHERE CreationDate > 'XXX'`（あるいは `LastActivityDate`？）などで最近の投稿にしぼると、トップページの印象に近付くのかな、と思いました。

Comment: 本家は派手に投票が入れられている印象でしたが、謂われてみるとトップページはどこも少ないですね。ちなみに、日本語版BetaとMetaでは投票の熱に差があるなという気がしています。投票呼びかけのために、この意識の違いを調査してみるのも参考になるかもしれません。

Comment: @Haru そもそもメイン・サイトとメタ・サイトでは投票の意味が違います。メタにおける投票は「良い投稿」「悪い投稿」を[必ずしも意味しません](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)。この違いも Haru さんがお持ちの印象に関係しているかもしれません。

Answer (score 1):

私は、他と比較して日本語版のトップページの投票が特段に少ないという印象は受けませんでした。
そもそも、トップページには新しい投稿が並びますから、投票数が少なくなりがちで、それにより寂れた印象が生まれるならば、それはデザインの問題です。

投票が機能せずにノイズだらけになっている、という状況でもないと思います。
少しでも問題がある投稿にはマイナス票が集中しています。
新しい訪問者へは強い自治がある「恐いサイト」という印象を与え、むしろ威嚇している位ではないでしょうか。