# 結果発表: 2018年 夏の投稿キャンペーン

Tags: 討議, 投票, キャンペーン

今年の春に「キャンペーンを行いませんか」という[お声](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2660/14055)をいただき、スタック・オーバーフロー 日本語版ではこの度、**夏の投稿キャンペーンを企画しました！** 日本語版モデレーターチームの多大なる協力により可能となりました。

今回の賞品はスタック・オーバーフロー オリジナルTシャツです。

[image: Men's]

[image: Women's]

**以下の各部門のWinner 合計４名にお送りします。** 投稿期間は2018年の7月30日(月)から8月10日(金)まで、結果発表は8月27日(月)に[Metaサイト](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/)にて行います。（結果発表までの2週間は投票を得る機会を増やすためのものです。）

1. 期間中に最も多くの質問を投稿したユーザー
2. 期間中に最も多くの回答を投稿したユーザー
3. 期間中に最も多くの投票を得た質問の投稿者
4. 期間中に最も多くの投票を得た回答の投稿者

### [キャンペーン内容]

#### - 対象

スタック・オーバーフロー ユーザー 
(信用度が低い人も高い人も中くらいの人も、全員)

#### - 期間とエントリー方法

7/30(月)から8/10(金)までに[スタック・オーバーフロー Betaサイト](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/)に投稿（質問でも、回答でも！）してください。こちらで集計するので特別なエントリーは不要です。

***Metaサイトでの回答はノーカウントとします。 
　　***Tシャツの海外発送は可能です。
　　***時間はスタック・オーバーフロー上の表示に従います。つまり、UTCです。

#### - 賞品

スタック・オーバーフロー Tシャツ

***プラスα？もしかすると他にも何か嬉しいものがもらえるかもしれません（^人^）

#### - 発表

8/27(月)Metaサイトにて 
Winnerの方々へは発表後にTシャツサイズと送付先を確認するためのemailが送られます。

#### おまけ：各部門のSQL *\(^o^)/*

[SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) で実行できます

1) [期間中に最も多くの質問を投稿したユーザー](https://data.stackexchange.com/ja/query/873365)

```sql
SELECT p.OwnerUserId AS [User Link], COUNT (DISTINCT p.Id) AS Number
FROM Posts p
WHERE p.PostTypeId = 1 AND p.CreationDate >= '2018-07-30' AND p.CreationDate < '2018-08-11'
GROUP BY p.OwnerUserId
ORDER BY Number DESC;
```

2) [期間中に最も多くの回答を投稿したユーザー](https://data.stackexchange.com/ja/query/873412)

```sql
SELECT p.OwnerUserId AS [User Link], COUNT (DISTINCT p.Id) AS Number
FROM Posts p
WHERE p.PostTypeId = 2 AND p.CreationDate >= '2018-07-30' AND p.CreationDate < '2018-08-11'
GROUP BY p.OwnerUserId
ORDER BY Number DESC;
```

3) [期間中に最も多くの投票を得た質問の投稿者](https://data.stackexchange.com/ja/query/873414)

```sql
SELECT p.Score, p.OwnerUserId AS [User Link], p.Id AS [Post Link]
FROM Posts p
WHERE p.PostTypeId = 1 AND p.CreationDate >= '2018-07-30' AND p.CreationDate < '2018-08-11'
ORDER BY p.Score DESC;
```

4) [期間中に最も多くの投票を得た回答の投稿者](https://data.stackexchange.com/ja/query/873417)

```sql
SELECT p.Score, p.OwnerUserId AS [User Link], p.Id AS [Post Link]
FROM Posts p
WHERE p.PostTypeId = 2 AND p.CreationDate >= '2018-07-30' AND p.CreationDate < '2018-08-11'
ORDER BY p.Score DESC;
```

たくさんの質問、回答、そして投票をお待ちしております！

Comment: @皆様 たくさんのご投稿ありがとうございました！

Answer (score 9):

**結果発表**

1. 期間中に最も多くの質問を投稿したユーザー 
   **payaneco さん。(11件)**
   [image: payaneco]
2. 期間中に最も多くの回答を投稿したユーザー
   **Yasuhiro Niji さん。(26件)**
   [image: yasuhiro-niji]
3. 期間中に最も多くの投票を得た質問の投稿者
   **yukihane さん。(+14)**
   [image: yukihane]
   [Windowsでファイル名の末尾ドットが無視される挙動の由来](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/47292/windows%E3%81%A7%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E5%90%8D%E3%81%AE%E6%9C%AB%E5%B0%BE%E3%83%89%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%E3%81%8C%E7%84%A1%E8%A6%96%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B%E6%8C%99%E5%8B%95%E3%81%AE%E7%94%B1%E6%9D%A5)
4. 期間中に最も多くの投票を得た回答の投稿者
   **sayuri さん。(+23)**
   [image: sayuri]
   [Windowsでファイル名の末尾ドットが無視される挙動の由来](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/47292/windows%E3%81%A7%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E5%90%8D%E3%81%AE%E6%9C%AB%E5%B0%BE%E3%83%89%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%E3%81%8C%E7%84%A1%E8%A6%96%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B%E6%8C%99%E5%8B%95%E3%81%AE%E7%94%B1%E6%9D%A5/47293#47293)

おめでとうございます！！！

ご参加いただいたみなさんへ
たくさんの質問、回答、投票をいただき本当にありがとうございました❤️o(^-^)o
これが最後ではありません！
次回のキャンペーンもどうぞよろしくお願いいたしますm_ _m

Comment: Winner の皆様へ：追って T シャツのための情報がメールされると思います。スタック・オーバーフローアカウントに紐づいているメールアドレスを再度ご確認くださいませ。（私は以前、あまり見ないアドレスを紐づけていたせいで確認に時間がかかったことがあります……）

Comment: Winner の皆様へ : 「スタック・オーバーフロー キャンペーンTシャツの送付について」というタイトルのメールをお送りいたしました。ご返信のほどどうぞよろしくお願いいたします。